# Using BFS find furthest located vertex from given vertex and its distance

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search

Instruction: Find the vertex which is farthest from v. If there is more than one such vertex, return the one with the smallest index.
Assume that the input graph is connected.
Return the pair which consists of the farthest vertex and its distance from v.

Please, give me some suggestions how can I modify BFS so that I can solve this task.
Thanks.

```
pair<int, int> Graph::findFarthestVertex(int v)
{
    int farthest = v;
    int maxdist = 0;
    int n = this->getVerticesCount();

    if(n==1)
    {
        farthest=0;
        maxdist=0;
        return pair<int, int>(farthest, maxdist);
    }

    int* visited = new int[n];
    queue<int> q;

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        visited[i]=0;

    q.push(v);
    visited[v]=1;

    while(q.empty()==false)
    {
        int elem = q.front();
        q.pop();

        for(int i=0; i<getNeighbors(elem).size(); ++i)
        {
            if(visited[elem]==0)
            {
                q.push(elem);
                visited[elem]=1;
            }

        }

    }

    return pair<int, int>(farthest, maxdist);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the expected output of your code, and what does it actually return? I.e. what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Either you need to give more information or this problem in NP-hard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @ShashwatKumar this is not the longest path problem.

Comment: Explanation:
Actually I have to create a function "pair<int, int> Graph::findFarthestVertex(int v)" that returns a pair, that pair is: 
1. the farthest located vertex from given (as an argument of this function) vertex v,
2. distance between vertex v and the farthest located vertex from v, that is distance in number of edges between those two vertices.

n is the number of all vertices in the graph.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then this shouldn't be hard I think. Just run bfs, and count distance of each node from v. When done with bfs, return node(s) with largest distance from v @displayed_name